# Listening To Timestamps in Database Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, events, laravel, laravel-4

I have been having some trouble finding a way to add a Laravel listener to a database. Basically, I have a database full of posts, and if a user hasn't updated a for 3 months, I want to send them an email reminding them to do it.

I have looked at laravel events, which may work. I also had the idea of running a continuous loop that checks if a timestamp has passed the 3 months mark, but that seems inefficient. What would be the best way to implement this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Just run a cron task once a day to look for users that have not posted in over 3 months. There's no need to be any fancier than that, no?